# Parsing JSON data using JavaScript push - want to prevent automatically closing divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I'm working on parsing JSON data and converting it to html form. 
I'm using the javascript **push** function, which I thought would push the data into the array I've designated it to in the order I push it. However, whenever I push a new div element, it is automatically closed after being pushed making the html come out in a different order I want. Is there a way I can prevent this?

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){


    var container = $('.panel-body');
    var jsonObj = $.parseJSON('{"fields":[{"label":"Nafn form / Form name","field_type":"sFormName","required":false,"field_options":{"size":"small"},"cid":"c2"},{"label":"Spurning 1 ","field_type":"QuestionText","required":false,"field_options":{"size":"small"},"cid":"c5"},{"label":"Spurning 2","field_type":"QuestionCheckbox","required":false,"field_options":{"options":[{"label":"","checked":false},{"label":"","checked":false}]},"cid":"c9"},{"label":"Spunring 4","field_type":"QuestionRadio","required":false,"field_options":{"options":[{"label":"Val","checked":false},{"label":"VAl ","checked":false},{"label":"Val","checked":false}],"include_other_option":false},"cid":"c13"},{"label":"Spurning með multi","field_type":"QuestionMultiBegin","required":false,"field_options":{"options":[{"label":"","checked":false},{"label":"","checked":false}]},"cid":"c17"},{"label":"Spurning","field_type":"QuestionDropdown","required":false,"field_options":{"options":[{"label":"Val","checked":false},{"label":"Val","checked":false},{"label":"Val","checked":false}],"include_blank_option":false},"cid":"c21"},{"label":"Skráning","field_type":"Registration","required":false,"field_options":{"options":[{"label":"Notendanafn / Username"},{"label":"Lykilorð / Password"}],"include_blank_option":false},"cid":"c25"}]}');

    var body = [];
    var headerData = jsonObj.fields;
    console.log(headerData);

    for (var i = 0; i < headerData.length; i++) {

        if(jsonObj.fields[i].field_type == "sFormName") {

          body.unshift("<div class='panel panel-default panel-element'><div class='panel-heading'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].label)

        } else {

          body.push("<div class='panel panel-default panel-element'><div class='panel-heading'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].label); 
        }                    

        if (jsonObj.fields[i].field_type == "QuestionText") {

         body.push("<div class='panel-body'><textarea class='large-text form-control'></textarea></div>");   

        } else if (jsonObj.fields[i].field_type == "QuestionParagraph") {

          body.push(jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.description);

        } else if (jsonObj.fields[i].field_type == "QuestionDropdown") {

           var data = jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options;

          body.push("<div class='panel-body'><div class='dropdown'><button class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown' id='dropdownMenu1' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='true'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options[0].label + "<span class='caret'></span></button>");

          body.push("<ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby=dropdownMenu1'>");
          for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
              body.push("<li><a href='#'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options[j].label + "</a></li>");
            }   

          body.push("</ul></div></div>");

        } else if (jsonObj.fields[i].field_type == "QuestionRadio") {

          var data = jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options;

          body.push("<div class='panel-body'>");

          for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
              body.push("<div class='radio'><div class='controls'><input type='radio' name='radio'></input>" + jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options[j].label);
            }   

          body.push("</div></div></div></div>");

        } else if (jsonObj.fields[i].field_type == "Registration") {

          body.push("<div class='panel-body'>");
          body.push("<div class='form-group'><form class='reg-form' role='form'><div class='form-group'><label for='email'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options[0].label + "</label>");
          body.push("<input type'email' class='form-control' id='email'></div>");
          body.push("<div class='form-group'><form class='reg-form' role='form'><div class='form-group'><label for='pwd'>" + jsonObj.fields[i].field_options.options[1].label + "</label>");
          body.push("<input type'password' class='form-control' id='pwd'></div>");
          body.push("<div class='checkbox'><label><input type='checkbox'> Muna mig / Remember me</label></div></form></div>");  
      }

    $(container).html(body);
}});
```

As you can see, I wrote the code assuming that I would have to push an ending div to each element that I'd opened, however that seems to be ignored.

Comment: As you are already using it elsewhere, it seems like you should be using jQuery to create the elements (`$('<div class="form-group"/>')`) then using jQuery [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) etc to build up the DOM. this should be much easier to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to pass the `body` array to the `html` method, however you should instead concatenate all strings inside of it, the pass it.

Like so:

```
var htmlMarkup = body.reduce(function(){
    return prev + current;
}, '');
```

or use 'join' as suggested by Hacketo, since it's less verbose:

```
var htmlMarkup = body.join('');

$(container).html(htmlMarkup);
```